# ShortCode and extra </p>

Tags: shortcode, html

[box id='1' text="some texte"]

the shortcode, at one point is outputting text

the html result is : `</p> some text </p>`

There is an extra closing paragraph in the start and and opening at the end... WHY ?

where those come from ?.... any idea ?.. it screw my w3 validation !

** note i have found that... but look all "patched" to me...any clean solution... wp is dirty ? [reference](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/shortcode-is-being-surrounded-by-p-tags)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discover that it's a know bug, and will be fix in future release [Reference here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12061) So then, i used this code... not pretty, but do the magic !, thanks

```
$content = do_shortcode( shortcode_unautop( $content ) );
if ( '</p>' == substr( $content, 0, 4 )
and '<p>' == substr( $content, strlen( $content ) - 3 ) )
    $content = substr( $content, 4, strlen( $content ) - 7 );
return '<div my stuff>' . $content . '</div>';
```

Comment: menardmam, `<p>` still remains - how to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and checked the $content in the add_filter() function. There you can see what happen with the shortcodes. I ended up with an easy plugin, that removes silly p and br tags on shortcodes:
http://www.johannheyne.de/wordpress/shortcode-empty-paragraph-fix/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is a double line-break before **and** after the shortcode in the editor;

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>   consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean
>   sodales, neque vitae imperdiet
>   aliquet, elit tortor egestas dui, vel
>   fermentum neque est eu est.
>
> [box id='1' text="some texte"]
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...

Comment: does not change anything.... or just add : # </p>
# <p>&nbsp;</p>

Answer (score 0):

When using a shortcode in the block editor, I had a really hard time removing extra p tags until I used the "**Custom HTML**" block and inserted the shortcode in there.

Hope this helps someone out there like me.